# How to get rows with most recent nulls?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

For the following:

```
col1 col2
1     null
3     null
5     100
6     200
10    null
11    201
```

How do I get the most recent col2==null rows using LINQ?  This would be only col1= (1,3). These values are coming from a database.

The result set would be:

```
col1 col2
1     null
3     null
```

Comment: What is the definition of more recent?

Comment: So what is your desired result, what have you tried? What means _"only col1= (1,3)"_?

Comment: So as sql you want this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/439be/6/0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not so familiar with `Linq-To-Sql`, so i'm not sure if it is supported, but try:

```
var query = db.TableName
    .Where(r1 => r1.Col2 == null 
            &&  r1.Col1 < db.TableName
                  .Where(r2 => r2.Col1 != null)
                  .Select(r2 => r2.Col1)
                  .OrderBy(col1 => col1)
                  .FirstOrDefault());
```

At least it should be the LINQ equivalent of this (working) sql-query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/439be/6/0